# JButton covers entire content pane

Tags: java, swing

I wanted to add a jbutton in jframe using swing.

```
JFrame jframe=new JFrame();
jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
jframe.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
JButton jbutton=new JButton("a");
jframe.getContentPane().add(jbutton);
jframe.pack();
jframe.setVisible(true);
```

The problem is jbutton is covering the entire jframe. I just wanted to display jbutton of default size in the content pane.

Comment: Read this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [`BorderLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/BorderLayout.html) will allow anything added to the `BorderLayout.WEST`, `BorderLayout.EAST`, `BorderLayout.NORTH`, `BorderLayout.SOUTH` spots to only take up as much space a needed and anything added to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` to take up all of the remaining space.

Try this...

```
JFrame jframe=new JFrame();
jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
jframe.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
Container content = jframe.getContentPane(); // Get the content pane
content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
JButton jbutton=new JButton("a");
content.add(jbutton, BorderLayout.WEST);
jframe.pack();
jframe.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: How can constants like Borderlayout.WEST work for flow layout. What is then use of setting to BorderLayout ?

Comment: @user2653926 As I know the default layout for a content pane is BorderLayout. FlowLayout is default for a normal JPanel